# I'm attempting to compare data from two input files to see if one set is less than the other

Tags: c++, arrays, fstream

I'm trying to compare data from one file to another to see if it "fits" inside the other. I'm thinking of one set as "Holes" and the other as "Blocks." I'm trying to see if all circle blocks fit inside at least one circle hole. If they all fit, I want to output "YES." If one does not fit, I want to output "NO, all circle blocks do not fit into at least one hole."

Heres my code:

```
    bool fits = false;

    for (int i=0; i<M; i++)
    {
      if (btype[i] == Circles)
      {
        CA[i] = (3.14 * (D[i] * D[i]));
      }

      for (int j=0; j<N; j++)
      {
        if (htype[j] == Circle)
        {
          CA[j] = (3.14 * (A[j] * A[j]));
        }

        if (CA[i] < CA[j])
        {
          fits = true;
          break;
        }
      }

      if (!fits)
      {
        break;
      }   
    }
    if (fits)
    {
      cout << "5. YES, all circle blocks fit a hole. "
           << endl;
    }
    else
    {
      cout << "5. NO, all circle blocks don't fit a hole. "
           << endl;
    }
```

The code is not acting right. When I put a circle value into the input file that should definitely make the program cout a NO, it give me a YES. I can't figure it out.

Comment: your if statement where you print YES or NO is inside of a for loop that will execute `N` times. So you will always get `N` output lines.

Comment: How do I take it outside the loop and still make it work when it's dependent on the if conditional (CirArea[i] < CirArea[j]) to say yes or no?

Comment: It's (slightly) easier to understand when properly indented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the if statement that does the printing inside the last for loop.

```
for (int j=0; j<N; j++)
{
   if (htype[j] == Circle)
   {
      CirArea[j] = (3.14 * (A[j] * A[j]));
   }


   if (CirArea[i] < CirArea[j])
   {
      cout << "5. YES, all circle blocks fit in a hole. " << endl;
   }
   else
   {
      cout << "5. NO, all circle blocks don't fit a hole. " << endl;
   }
}
```

If you want to print the message depending on if one doesn't fit, and if all fit then print another message you can do it like this.

```
float fits = 0.0;
float nofit = 0.0;
bool result;

for (int i=0; i<M; i++)
{
  result = false;

  if (btype[i] == Circles)
  {
    CirArea[i] = (3.14 * (D[i] * D[i]));
  }

  for (int j=0; j<N; j++)
  {
    if (htype[j] == Circle)
    {
      CirArea[j] = (3.14 * (A[j] * A[j]));
    }

    if (CirArea[i] < CirArea[j])
    {
       result = true;
       //exit inner loop
       break;
    }
  }

  if (!result)
  {
     //exit outer loop
     break;
  }
}

if (result)
{
    cout << "5. YES, all circle blocks fit in a hole. " << endl;
}
else
{
    cout << "5. NO, all circle blocks don't fit a hole. " << endl;
}
```

Comment: If I pull it out, the program won't compile because error: name lookup of ‘i’ changed for new ISO ‘for’ scoping

Comment: So do I need to declare int i = 0; and int j = 0; outside the for loop?

Comment: Yeh, sorry, you can't pull it out like I originally specified, me being the noob I am didn't look to see how you were doing the comparison. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Ah a bool. I am dumb. THanks for the tip

Comment: I think this algorithm, (the one you wrote above) is actually giving a false result because it outputs "NO" as soon as CA[i] fails the bool condition. CA[i] doesn't necessarily have to be less than CA[j], just as long as it's less than at least one CA[j] then it should cout YES. Is there a way to put that condition in there?

Comment: Just edited so try it now.  If it finds a match it exits the inner loop as that circle block is a "YES".  If all circle blocks exit the inner loop with a "YES" then it will print the "YES" message. If a circle block exits the inner loop without finding a match, then it will exit the outer loop as well with a "NO" and it will print the "NO" message. Is that what you want?

Comment: NO, I don't think this works either because it's still giving me the wrong answer.

Comment: I have three circles in each input file. They are all the same dimensions as their counterpart in the opposite input file. The program should output a YES, all blocks fit at least one hole.

Comment: I tried removing the if (!result); break; and it kind of worked. I got a false positive though. I added a huge circle to the array that could make the program output a NO. It worked when the huge circle was in the last spot in the array but when I moved it up to the middle it didn't work anymore.

Comment: If you want circles of the same size as the holes to fit, you need to change the test to less than or equal to, i.e `if (CirArea[i] <= CirArea[j])`.

Answer (score 0):

As the lines with **cout** are inside the **for** loop with **N** iterations, which is inside another **for** loop with **M** iterations, looks like it should print **M * N** lines